# Use implicit differentiation to find all points on the curve with a given slope

Tags: calculus

Consider the curve $R^2$ given by the equation:

$x^2 - y^2 = 1$

a/ Use the method of implicit differentiation to find all points on the curve at which that tangent has a slope of $\frac53$

b/ Explain why there are no points on the curve at which the tangent is horizontal.

So far, I have found the implicit differentiation, which is
$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x}y$. Can you guys help me what should I do next. Any help is appreaciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

1. Solve $\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{x}{y}=\pm \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}= \frac {5}{3}$
2. If slope is 0, then $y^2=-1$, is it possible?

Comment: Really appreciate your help, this is exactly what I'm looking for